# Add Route to VPN on Windows 7

Tags: windows, powershell, vpn

I'm having a problem finding any command that is able to replace Add -VpnConnectionRoute which is only available on Windows 10.
I'm working on Windows 7 PC.
I need to connection route to Point to Point VPN.
How can i workaround this on Windows 7?

Comment: [New-NetRoute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/new-netroute?view=winserver2012-ps)?

Comment: what have you tried? what did not work as expected? what errors did you get?